# How to execute multi-stated SQL in QlikView script?

Tags: sql-server, qlikview

I have a MS-SQL query, using temporary table, which from I'd like to get data into QlikView:

```
declare @oi_im table (tick datetime);

insert into @oi_im
SELECT TOP 360 dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, GETDATE()) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID), 0) as tick
FROM [Messages] timer;

SELECT tick as Created, case when msgs is NULL then 0 else msgs end as msgs
FROM (SELECT TOP 360 tick
FROM @oi_im) timer
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 360 dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, Created), 0) as Created, count(*) as msgs
  FROM [Messages] with(nolock)
  GROUP BY dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, Created), 0)
  ORDER BY Created desc) msgslist ON msgslist.Created=timer.tick
ORDER BY timer.tick desc
```

My first try was to just copy this text into QlickWiev "Edit Script" window, but the problem is - script throws statements into SQL one by one.
After making first statement (make temporary table) MS SQL server loses the context, and on second statement produces error "I don't know any @oi_im"

Next try is to wrap this text into stored procedure:

```
SQL execute sp_executesql N'declare @oi_im table (tick datetime);


insert into @oi_im
SELECT TOP 360 dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, GETDATE()) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID), 0) as tick
FROM [Messages] timer with(nolock);


SELECT tick as Created, case when msgs is NULL then 0 else msgs end as msgs
FROM (SELECT TOP 360 tick
FROM @oi_im) timer
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 360 dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, Created), 0) as Created, count(*) as msgs
  FROM [Messages] with(nolock)
  GROUP BY dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, 0, Created), 0)
  ORDER BY Created desc) msgslist ON msgslist.Created=timer.tick
ORDER BY timer.tick desc
'
```

It produces no error, but unfortunately returns no data at all.

So the question is: how to execute multi-stated SQL in QlikView script, while first SQL statement is not a SELECT?

Comment: I don't know anything about qlikview but you have a couple of issues with your sql. First is using top 360 with no order by. When you do this you have no way of knowing which rows you will get. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx Second is that NOLOCK hint. Do you know all the issues with that hint and what it really does?

Comment: Hi Sean!

First: I use ORDER BY with second query, where it is really needed. The first one works fine with no ORDER BY at all. I don't know how and why, but as long as it works - I do not repair it.

Second: yes, I read how this hint works, what it can and what it can not...
And this is corporate policy to use it :)

Comment: The first one works if you don't care which rows you get back. It will return 360 but you don't know which ones. If you read the article I posted it explains why see what you see. It will at some point stop getting the correct rows and will drive you nuts. Save yourself the hassle and put an order by on there. Your corporate policy is totally flawed if they require you to get inaccurate results in every query. That hint is dangerous at best and destructive at its worst. I have been in shops where that policy was enforced and when see what it means it can be changed.

Comment: Thank you, Sean, there actually is error, but bot that one you mentioned. Very first SELECT has ORDER BY, so the second SELECT (from temp table) actually doesn't need TOP.
Anyway, all that has not so much sense as long as I cannot get data into QlikView.

Comment: Yeah I can't help with the Qlikview part. I would however suggest that your first query does not have an order by, you see one because it is in the ROW_NUMBER window function but the actual query is just going to get the first 360 rows and there is no logical order to it. If that doesn't matter then no biggie. :)

Comment: Loading data to Qlikview from an SP is pretty straight forward.  I am a bit confused though, you say you are wrapping it in an SP, but what looks like your Qlikview script isn't calling a stored procedure, its calling embedded SQL.  If you can confirm that that does generate a result then put it in a Stored Proc and Execute the stored procedure http://www.learnallbi.com/executing-stored-procedure-in-qlikview/

Comment: A possible solution would be not to use a temp table. Instead rewriting all into one nested SELECT statement.

Comment: Hi, ralfbecher! Using one nested SELECT was a first attempt, but it had one great disadvantage - counting a result of 360 rows took over 30 seconds. I suppose it was because of lack of index, but I'm not sure. Anyway, regular load for production server over 30 seconds is not a considerable option.

Comment: But how can a temp table be faster then?

Comment: ralfbecher, I don't know how and why, but the fact is: 1) one big query takes over 30 seconds, 2) composite statement with temp table does it in less than second.      Anyway, the main question still matter - how to execute multi-stated SQL in QlikView script?